Drag to edit Outlook calendar item
If I create a multi-day Outlook (version 16.0) calendar item it appears at the top of the calendar in the weekly view. If I hover over the edge a "drag to resize" icon appears as seen in the picture, however dragging does nothing. It would be very convenient to edit items by dragging, so I am wondering if this is a problem with my setup or if it is a software bug.

For reference, it works fine to drag to edit items in the daily view.

It seems that Microsoft hasn't developed the drag-resize feature in depth yet. I've created a daily event (not an all-day event) that I can edit in all views (extend/shorten the activity duration), but for an all-day event, I can only drag it to change the date (e.g. dragging a December 1 event to a December 2 event) doesn't make it longer (i.e. one day becomes two days), I'm afraid you have to manually adjust it for now.

However, it seems you can resize the all day event in Month View.

The above test operation was on Outlook for Web, I retried it in the client, including the new and classic versions, which are allowed to customize the duration of the all-day event in both Week and Month View by dragging to resize. More information: https://usercomp.com/news/1436820/drag-and-edit-multi-day-outlook-calendar-item

Cool, so swapping to Month view is a temporary workaround until they fixed it

Yes, it is like this at the moment, and you can also stay tuned for updates from it.
